# Keep Screen On When Watching Online Videos

Tags: 14.04, firefox, video, power-management, screen

I really like Ubuntu 14.04 so far. But when I watch a video on-line, I need to move my mouse every few minutes to avoid screen going black - highly annoying and doesn't make much sense when nearly everyone is watching movies/videos on-line.

I know this was asked in the past - but I am looking for a solution that does not require creating scripts (or multiple scripts). I'm also not looking for an external way to halt screen-dimming in general (Caffeine) or to artificially move my mouse every few minutes.

I'm asking how to get this functionality in the OS itself?

Considering the other thread was asked four years ago, and this concerns pretty much every user, I assume this functionality was added already (?) so this will hopefully be useful for many other users.

Thanks

EDIT: If there is no solution to this, is there a bug report for this issue? Considering it has been a problem for many years..

Comment: It doesn't help a lot if you do not want to use existing "external" solutions. If your browser doesn't do the job, how do you figure it should work *without* scripts or global settings?

Comment: Well, I use FF in other non-Linux platforms, and it doesn't do that in any of them - and this is not a new issue.
If there is a way to make this happen with an ad-on it's better than nothing. But I don't like giving adons control over power management if I can help it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to disable the "Dim screen to save power" option and adjust the screen timeout under Brightnes & Lock in settings.

Comment: Thanks, I am not looking for a global setting that would affect the computer when doing other things. In other words, I want the dim screen to work normally when not watching videos.

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: I am using FF and sometimes Chrome.